# RegEx should match URLs which doesn't have numbers (0-9) and concrete words for example cat and dog

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-group

to not select URLs like this one:

```
https://www.shalqlq.com/image/something/51227/
https://www.shalqlq.com/something/40392/video/51232/
https://www.something.com/cat/hello_world/
https://www.sxxxomething.com/dog/image/
```

but to select

```
https://www.somethinxxxg.com/world/fin/
https://www.sometxhiaaxng.com/something/videbo/
https://www.shalqlq.com/image/something
```

I tryed this regEx but it only ignors URLs with numbers and I don't know how to add the words cat and dog in order to exclude them as well ^((?!/([\d]+)/).)*$

Comment: Consider `^(?!.*(?:\d|cat|dog)).*`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7WLsKo/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extended your regex: now it should works. It also ignores URLs with the words "cat" and "dog".

`^((?!/([\d]+)/|cat|dog).)*$`

But here is my version of the Regex:
it should do the same, but is more performant:
`^(?:(?>[^/]+)(?<!\d|dog|cat)(?>/*))*$`
Explanations:

- `(?>...)` means, that the Regex matches the `...` at whole and prevent backtracking.
- `(?:...)` that the Regex not captures matches within the `(...)`

Comment: Note that the end-of-string anchor is not needed.